# When uploading an image, the image doesn't change but the image URL is correct

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying out wordpress widgets, and I took this code from https://vedmant.com/using-wordpress-media-library-in-widgets-options/. The widget is supposed to let you upload your own images via the wordpress media library. The code works to open up the media library, upload an image and choose it, but the image won't change to show the new image.

Here's the code (also on the site):

I read some other treads on similar things, and tried to look up refreshing widgets, but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for. I think the problem is that the textbox will fill with the image URL but it won't refresh because Wordpress thinks nothing changed. Any ideas on what I can do?

```
<?php 
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myw_init' );

function myw_init() {
register_widget( 'my_widget' );
}

class my_widget extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Sets up the widgets name etc
 */
 function __construct() {

      // Add Widget scripts
      add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'scripts'));

      parent::__construct(
         'my_widget', // Base ID
         __( 'Our Widget Title', 'text_domain' ), // Name
         array( 'description' => __( 'Our Widget with media files', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
      );
   }
/**
 * Enqueue scripts
 */
public function scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'media-upload' );
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script('mfc-media-upload', get_template_directory_uri() . '/../../plugins/my-featured-content/mfc-media-upload.js', array('jquery'));
}        

/**
 * Outputs the content of the widget
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @param array $instance
 */
 public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    // Our variables from the widget settings
    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? __( 'Default title', 'text_domain' ) : $instance['title'] );
    $image = ! empty( $instance['image'] ) ? $instance['image'] : '';

    ob_start();
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
       echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
    }
    ?>

    <?php if($image): ?>
       <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image); ?>" alt="">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    echo $args['after_widget'];
    ob_end_flush();
 }

/**
 * Outputs the options form on admin
 *
 * @param array $instance The widget options
 */
 public function form( $instance ) {
    $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
    $image = ! empty( $instance['image'] ) ? $instance['image'] : '';
    ?>
    <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Image:' ); ?></label>
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" />
       <button class="upload_image_button button button-primary">Upload Image</button>
    </p>
    <?php
 }

/**
 * Processing widget options on save
 *
 * @param array $new_instance The new options
 * @param array $old_instance The previous options
 *
 * @return array
 */
 public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
    $instance['image'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['image'] ) ) ? $new_instance['image'] : '';

    return $instance;
 }
}
```

And for the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $(document).on("click", ".upload_image_button", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var $button = $(this);


     // Create the media frame.
     var file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Select or upload image',
        library: { // remove these to show all
           type: 'image' // specific mime
        },
        button: {
           text: 'Select'
        },
        multiple: false  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
     });

     // When an image is selected, run a callback.
     file_frame.on('select', function () {
        // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader

        var attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

        $button.siblings('input').val(attachment.url);

     });

     // Finally, open the modal
     file_frame.open();
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a query parameter to the image URL to force it to be unique, e.g.:

`<img src="<?php echo esc_url($image); ?>?<?php echo time() ?>" alt="">`